# tomcat process hogging all CPU and large amount of virtual memory

Tags: performance, tomcat

top shows that tomcat is using a small amount of resident memory but large amount virtual memory, is there a way to give it more resident memory?  I've tried JAVA_OPTS with -Xmx2g but resident memory still floats around 250 mg

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                            
28669 tomcat    20   0 9763m 297m 6224 S 704.4  0.6   1306:25 java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct command line switch for specifying maximum size of the memory allocation pool is `-Xmx`

Something like this should work for you: `-Xmx2g` in `JAVA_OPTS`

** Be careful while allocating very high memory to your JVM as it causes problems sometimes.

For your case I would suggest you to [enable remote JMX in your Tomcat process](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html#Enabling_JMX_Remote) And then once process shows unusually high CPU/memory usage connect with a JMX client such as jConsole or VisualVM and see if there is any deadlock or very long running threads.